# How to get a list of unique python modules imported from different scripts located in different folders

Tags: python, package, python-module, project-structure

I have a project contained in a folder (`src`). It is divided into different folders and each one contains some script `.py`. An example of the project structure is the following:

```
├── src                <- Source code for use in this project.
│   │
│   ├── data           <- Scripts to download or generate data.
│   │
│   ├── features       <- Scripts to turn raw data into features for modeling.
│   │
│   ├── models         <- Scripts to train models and then use trained models to make predictions.
```

Like I said before, inside each folder under `src` I have a different python script. For example:

```
├── data               
   │
   ├── create_dataframe.py
   ├── imputation.py
.
.
.
```

There is a way to get a list of all unique python modules used in each separate script?

For example, if I have in `create_dataframe.py`

```
import pandas as pd
```

and in `imputation.py` I have

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
from   tqdm import tqdm
```

The desired output would be

```
Output: ['pandas', 'numpy', 'tqdm']
```

I am not interested in the module's version. I just want the name of the module.

Comment: Do you also want `from x import y` in it?

Comment: No, just the module name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this script from `src` folder:

```
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path.cwd()
modules = set()

for file in path.glob('**/*.py'):
    lines = file.read_text(encoding='utf-8')
    for line in lines.split('\n'):
        if line.startswith('import ') or line.startswith('from '):
            modules.add(line.split()[1].replace(';','').replace(',',''))

for module in sorted(modules):
    print(module)
```

Comment: Ok, it works. But I want also the packaged imported using the `from` keyword. I edited the question. I edited also your answer just adding the second condition  `line.startswith('from ')`